# javascript ignores validation by just toggling the value of an aria attribute despite empty value

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I'm using the `aria-required` attribute in my HTML to check if the textbox is empty or not when blurred. If it has no value when blurred, it would be colored red, and back to white if it has a value. The result was surprising; it just toggles the boolean value of the attribute when focused and blurred and ignores the validation.

```js
var txtbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

function isBlank(query) {
  var required = (query.getAttribute('aria-required') === 'true');
  if(!query.value) {
    query.setAttribute('aria-required', !required);
    return true;
  } else {
    query.setAttribute('aria-required', required);
    return false;
  }
}

function validateTextbox(e) {
  var evt = e.target;
  
  isBlank(evt);
}

txtbox.addEventListener('blur', validateTextbox);
```

```css
[id="textbox"][aria-required="true"] {
  background: #f00;
}
[id="textbox"][aria-required="false"] {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="textbox">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Try focusing then blurring the textbox without a value, it toggles the attribute value of the `aria-required`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `!required` is inverting the boolean which is not what you want.

Here's a working example:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox')

function isBlank(target) {
  var required = (target.getAttribute('aria-required') === 'true')
  var isEmpty = !target.value.length

  target.setAttribute('aria-required', isEmpty)
  return isEmpty
}

function validateTextbox(event) {
  var target = event.target
  isBlank(target)
}

textbox.addEventListener('blur', validateTextbox)
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ekj8brav/5/**

Here's another way to validate input fields using the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute and styling it using CSS [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) and [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-selectors:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="textbox">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS

```
#textbox:invalid {
  background: #f00;
}

#textbox:valid {
  background: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox')

function isBlank(target) {
  var isEmpty = !target.value.length

  if (isEmpty) {
    target.setAttribute('required', true)
    target.setAttribute('aria-required', true)
  }

  return isEmpty
}

function validateTextbox(event) {
  var target = event.target
  isBlank(target)
}

textbox.addEventListener('blur', validateTextbox)
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eph607up/2/**

Comment: Is WAI-ARIA requisite in modern web development?

Comment: it's important, however it is neglected all the time because people think about accessibility as an after-thought, which sucks for disabled people who rely on wai-aria